# See all GET requests made when url is loaded in python

Tags: python, json, ajax, get, request

I am trying to scrape some data using python, from:

http://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/france/atp-french-open-2009/soderling-robin-federer-roger-CIfxjBDp/

The data in question is loaded via ajax through a GET request to

http://fb.oddsportal.com/feed/match/1-2-CIfxjBDp-3-2-yj886.dat?_=1459707047171

Lets call the first URL about url1 and the second one url2. In python, I want to give my script url1, and want it to generate url2 for me. I guess, it would need to somehow see all the GET requests that are run when url1 is loaded. Is there some way to do this in Python?

[image: Website Screenshot]

Comment: What are you trying to get exactly?

Comment: all the info from this page http://fb.oddsportal.com/feed/match/1-2-CIfxjBDp-3-2-yj0e6.dat?_=1459704840247  (which is called when you open url1)